# Receive Notification text info

Tags: java, android

If I get notification from twitter then I want to get all the text from it. if it's tweeted by user "ABCD" (@abcd) and the tweet contains "Hello" so "do this stuff".

So how can i get to that? Is there any notification receiver like broadcast receiver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the NotificationListenerService to receive the notifications. Then, depending on your app's requirements, parse the contents of the notification and perform your desired action.

[Here is the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) for NotificationListenerService. It looks fairly straight forward to set up. You'll need to add a node to your AndroidManifest.xml and then create a class that extends NotificationListenerService.

[Here is an example on Github of someone using the NotificationListenerService.](https://github.com/kpbird/NotificationListenerService-Example/)